# Calculate the electrical energy of a charged sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> Water from a metal vessel, maintained at a potential of 3 V, falls in spherical drops of 2mm in diameter through a small hole into a thin-walled isolated metal sphere of diameter 8cm placed in air until the sphere is completely filled with water. Ignoring the thickness of the metal, calculate the final potential of the sphere and its electrical energy.

I could find out the final potential as 4800V. That was easy. But how do I find out electrical energy? Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Shreshta and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the capacitance of an isolated spherical conductor in terms of the radius/diameter of the sphere and the energy stored in a capacitor in terms of the potential (difference).

Comment: Yeah. That did help. Infact I could just find out electrical energy using E=1/2 QV .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know the **resistance** offered then you can calculate electrical energy using
$$E=\frac{V^2t}{R}$$

And you can get the **time** $t$ in seconds by dividing the **volume** of the metal sphere by the **volume** of the water drop.

Comment: Actually that's my point. I have no clue how to find the resistance.